# Render request on Spring MVC application startup

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am developing a Spring/Spring MVC application where everything is working properly but I have some doubts about the application startup.

Right now, when Tomcat starts and the application starts I am receiving a render request on the "home" controller even I don't access the site. It's like it is done automatically. Is this correct? Can this be disabled and is there any reason why this is done by default?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you determine you are getting a request?

Comment: you start tomcat in debug mode, and it stops in your controller on startup ?

Comment: yes, exactly.. and I also see it in the logs... by the way look this DEBUG: org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer  - Render request recieved for definition 'user.home'
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Successfully completed request

Comment: And if I place a breakpoint it stops too. Not sure why, that's why I was asking if this is normal or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that when the defined DispatcherServlet is mapped to * like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You always get a request to your "home" controller that is mapped to /